# Linux script errors- syntax error near unexpected token fi

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have been working on this script for hours trying to find out why it doesn't run,
it keeps spitting out :

`"program.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token`fi'

`program.sh: line 23:`fi

here is a copy of the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is the program men
if [ $CHOICE = "1" ]; then
echo "removing old backup folder"
rm -rf ./AllBackUp
fi
echo "Backing up all files to ./Allbackup"
cp $PWD/* $PWD/AllBackUp
elif [ $CHOICE =  "2" ]; then
if  [ -d SelectBackup ];
rm -rf ./SelectBackup
fi
for f in $PWD; do
cp $PWD/$PATTERN $PWD/SelectBackup
done
```

help, I'm in a hole here!

Comment: better post the script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ and see its errors. Then, if something is unclear, [edit] to show a better format (I cleaned it a little already) and indicate your research.

Comment: ok, i will give it a try

Comment: Indent your code. what `if` does the `elif` belong to?

Answer (score 1):

Your second `if` statement is missing a `then`, so the `fi` is, indeed, unexpected. (Bash is still expecting a `then`.)